# Facebook connect silent logout along with my logout url?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, fbconnect

I have created a facebook connect login script in addition to the custom login script my site uses, which records FB user id and stores in my DB. It uses facebbok.php scripts provided by facebook and JS based popup login dialog (oauth).

I just authenticate user from FB account and do my own cookie based login on the basis of matched fb user id.

Now the problem is I can get logout url from php using getLogoutUrl() but how to logout silently without changing url in address bar using my logout.php? I tried destroySession() but it didnt logout fb user.

If user dont logout using getLogoutUrl() then next time when some other loggedin FB user tries to use fbconnect login the FB dialog box gives error "An error occurred. Please try later". Then I have go back to IE and logout that FB user from there and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "silently" logout a user using Facebook API. What you can do is test if the user is logged using [`getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)